# Не работает авторизация вк через приложение iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Я уже второй месяц бьюсь над внедрением авторизации через ВК в своё приложение, но пока без успехов. Пожалуйста помогите разобраться что я делаю не так. Вот мои последние попытки настроить вк (тестовое приложение) https://yadi.sk/d/JVaC72243FxMYU

Скажите что я делаю не так? Если возможно подскажите как правильно. Может где-то в plist я что-то не так сделал. Будет очень замечательно, если кто поделится своим проектом, где внедрён вк (если это возможно).

Я пробовал конвертировать пример приложения с Objective-c, но ничего не помогло. Так что буду рад если кто объяснить (желательно пошагово) как интегрировать VKSDK на swift 2 или 3 и авторизоваться.

Comment: не компилируется

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko странно. У меня версия xCode 8.2.1, может в этом дело? Я сейчас заменил ссылку на архив, там я вчера кое-что добавил.

Comment: у вас vksdk в проекте нет, а ссылка указывает на декстоп иди что то такое

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko да видимо у меня на рабочем столе папка просто была от VKSDK, поэтому она не перенеслась. Вот эта библиотека https://yadi.sk/d/7ocy--WX3G2DEn